# How to add a variable's value to an array function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the random number to the array which is assigned to a function that keeps adding the numbers together.

```
function getMiNumber(number){
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    value.push(value.value);

    var myArray = someCalc([0]);
    console.log(myArray);
    function showMe(val) {
      var presentMe = document.getElementById('someId');
      presentMe.innerHTML = val;
    }
    showMe(myArray);

            function someCalc(list) {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        total += list[i];
      }
      return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: well ... the argument `number` is never used in the function, `value.value` is undefined, as a Number does not have a property called value, and value doesn't have .push method, as it is not an Array ... that's just lines 1, 2 and 3 of your code - line 3 would produce an error in developer tools console ...

Comment: and line 5 will always result in the myArray being the value 0

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Reread the question and determined that a cumulative total is desired so this demo will:

- Generate a random number 1 to 10.

  - Display that number.
- Add that number to an array.

  - Display that array.
- Add all of the array's elements.

  - Display that total.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>34562147</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font: small-caps 400 16px/1.4 'Source Code Pro';
    }
    fieldset {
      border: 2px inset grey;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    legend {
      font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Random Array Total</legend>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="rand()" value="Random" />
    <br/>
    <label for="out0">Next:
      <output id="out0"></output>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label for="out1">Array:
      <output id="out1"></output>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label for="out2">Total:
      <output id="out2"></output>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <script>
    var xArray = [];

    function rand() {
      var ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      var out0 = document.getElementById('out0');
      var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
      var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');
      out0.value = ran1;
      xArray.push(ran1);
      out1.value = xArray;
      out2.value = calc(xArray);
    }

    function calc(xArray) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        total += xArray[i];
      }
      return total;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

---

## OLD

The array is pre-determined in this demo `var xArray = [23, 8, 90, 7];`

```js
function randomNumber(xArray){
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    xArray.push(value);
  return xArray;
}
    var xArray = [23, 8, 90, 7];
    var total = calc(randomNumber(xArray));
    console.log(total);
    function output(total) {
      var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
      out1.value = total;
    }
    

 function calc(list) {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        total += list[i];
      }
      return total;
    }

output(total);
```

```html
<output id="out1"></output>
```